# Angular 2 - Issue with "Parent listens for child event" sample given in angular.io

Tags: angular

I am trying to run a sample provided in [This URL](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#child-to-parent)

Based on the URL, i should create 2 components

- VoteTakerComponent (Parent - app.vote-taker.component.ts)
- VoterComponent (Child - app.voter.component.ts)

and bootstrap the Parent component. I have added code for all 3 major files i have used below

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { VoteTakerComponent } from './app.vote-taker.component';
import { VoterComponent } from './app.voter.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ VoteTakerComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ VoteTakerComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.vote-taker.component.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { Component }      from '@angular/core';
import { VoterComponent } from './app.voter.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'vote-taker',
  template: `
    <h2>Should mankind colonize the Universe?</h2>
    <h3>Agree: {{agreed}}, Disagree: {{disagreed}}</h3>
    <voter *ngFor="let voter of voters"
      (onVoted)="onVoted($event)">
    </voter>
  `
})

//[name]="voter"

export class VoteTakerComponent {
  agreed = 0;
  disagreed = 0;
  voters = ['Mr. IQ', 'Ms. Universe', 'Bombasto'];
  onVoted(agreed: boolean) {
    agreed ? this.agreed++ : this.disagreed++;
  }
}
```

**app.voter.component.ts**

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'voter',
  template: `
    <h4>{{name}}</h4>
    <button (click)="vote(true)"  [disabled]="voted">Agree</button>
    <button (click)="vote(false)" [disabled]="voted">Disagree</button>
  `
})

export class VoterComponent {
  @Input()  name: string;
  @Output() onVoted = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  voted = false;
  vote(agreed: boolean) {
    this.onVoted.emit(agreed);
    this.voted = true;
  }
}
```

I get the following error in browser console when i executed this code

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: 'voter' is not a
>   known element:
>   1. If 'voter' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'voter' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
>   ("uld mankind colonize the Universe?

When i searched web for this kind of error, 
its been mentioned that i should include **VoterComponent** in the declarations part of NgModules in **app.modules.ts** file, but when i add **VoterComponent**
in declarations tag as like below

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { VoteTakerComponent } from './app.vote-taker.component';
import { VoterComponent } from './app.voter.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ VoteTakerComponent, VoterComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ VoteTakerComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

But i get following error

> The selector "vote-taker" did not match any elements

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you importing the browsermodule?

Comment: you forgot to mention `VoterComponent` in the `@NgModule` declarations?

Comment: Did you actually use VoteTakerComponent in your html?

Comment: Yes, i am using browser module. it seems i should update the Html to reflect the tag used in the component as specified by Pankaj in the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you made `VoteTakerComponent` as bootstrap component,  you have to use `vote-taker` selector (root of your application) on page `index.html` page make application work.

```
<vote-taker>App is loading..</vote-taker>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Pankaj Parkar

Comment: @Pankaj Parker, Is it possible to validate textbox based on id attribute instead of name attribute using ng-messages?